# Typescript - require single literal value in N-length array

Tags: typescript

Is the following somehow possible? I want to require the 'foo' literal, but allow the array to be any shape (i.e. I can't use an X-length tuple with pre-defined positions)

```
type requireFoo = ???

const works: requireFoo = ['bar','foo'] //Should work
const notWork: requireFoo = ['tar', 'bar'] //Should not work
```

[Here's a playground template](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAThCOBXAlnAYgew1AvFA-IQFBEDGGAdgM7BQDuGMA1lQFywIrpa5QDaAcgBmWAQBooAgEYBDGAIC6UAPTKAygAsMiADYATeoyZlKNKBQzAA6kfZwkqCJmx5BwOeMmz5S1Zu365paGzCRAA)

Comment: If there's a problem in particular that you're trying to solve, you might want to post that as a question instead so that we might be able to provide a more ergonomic solution by changing both the javascript and the typings.

Answer (score 2):

It's a strange requirement. If you require foo occurs at the end or start of the tuple you can do this:

```
type requireFoo = [...any[], 'foo']

const works: requireFoo = ['bar', 'foo' as const] // Good 
const notWork: requireFoo = ['tar', 'bar' as const] // Bad
```

note: Rest arguments in the start of the tuple as shown above are only available in typscript 4.2 beta.